# animation not visible to other users

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-mirror

When the user presses the keys, I start the dance animations, but when I add it to the player, it only sees itself dancing, how can I solve it? I use *Mirror* networking

[image]

Answer (score 0):

lets say your object wanna dance
you need to tell the server "i wanna dance"
and in the server side you must dance after that you neeed to reflect your dance to all clients "he/she is dancing"

First of all you need to say
i wanna dance on client -> Dance(danceMoveNumberFive)
in this Dance(danceMoveNumberFive) function
Call CmdDance(danceMoveNumberFive) -> it will tell to the server this player wanna dance
And in this Command you must dance on the server side.
It means do your move. Change object rotation etc.
After that call RpcDance(DanceMoveNumberFive) ->Now server will reflect your dance to all client including the first client who tell the server "i wanna dance"
In this RpcDance(DanceMoveNumberFive) you will dance again but this time for all clients means, you need to set your object rotation again but this time it will shown to all clients

SyncDance
If your dance is Sync value then you dont need to reflect your dance to other clients by calling RpcDance()
Just tell the server i wanna dance and when your server object dance
Server it will automaticly reflect your dance on the all clients